# How can I run NamedPipeServerStream asynchronous?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I run NamedPipeServerStream asynchronous?

I'm not using the pipe in another computer through a server. I'm using it only on my computer. This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        //int i, j;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {

        }

        public void Start(string FileName, int BitmapRate )
        {
            p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
            b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // Some buffer for the R, G and B of pixels of an image of size 720p.
            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86\ffmpeg.exe";
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + FileName;
            process.Start();

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.WaitForConnection();
        }
```

Everything is working. The problem is when the process is started and I see the command prompt window and see all the work in the window. I can't get to the form. I can drag/move the command prompt window around the screen, but I can't get to the form window to click a button for example or stop the operation. I need to wait for it to finish first to do the work in the command prompt window or the window of the process.

Using the following line of code, I saw a property of the variable p to check if it's asynchronous or not but how do I set it to be asynchronous at all?

```
p.IsAsync
```

I tried to find examples, but they are all according to servers between two computers with security stuff I think.

Later, I changed this line:

```
p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

Added in the end: PipeOptions.Asynchronous

Now when I'm running my application, I'm getting exception on the line:

```
p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
```

Exception:

> InvalidOpertionException: Pipe hasn't been connected yet.

This is my full code with all changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        //int i, j;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        IAsyncResult ar;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {

        }

        public void Start(string FileName, int BitmapRate )
        {
            p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
            b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // Some buffer for the R G and B of pixels of an image of size 720p.
            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86\ffmpeg.exe";
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + FileName;
            process.Start();

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            ar = p.BeginWaitForConnection(EndWait,null);
        }

        void EndWait(IAsyncResult iar)
        {
            var state = ar.AsyncState; //fetch result, mandatory!
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            int length;
            // Lock the bitmap's bits.
            //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
            // Get the address of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
            length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

            //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
            int j = bmp.Height - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
            {
                IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                j--;
            }

            p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

The exception message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Pipe hasn't been connected yet.
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckWriteOperations()
       at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Ffmpeg.PushFrame(Bitmap bmp) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Ffmpeg.cs:line 77
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.StartRecording_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Form1.cs:line 53
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`NamedPipeServerStream.WaitForConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.waitforconnection.aspx) your current thread will block until the operation has finished.
You can use [`BeginWaitForConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.beginwaitforconnection.aspx) to create a thread that will work in background.
Using the returned `IAsyncResult`, you can fetch the result of the asynchronous operation.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx):

The IAsyncResult interface is implemented by classes containing methods that can operate asynchronously. It is the return type of methods that initiate an asynchronous operation, such as `FileStream.BeginRead`, and it is passed to methods that conclude an asynchronous operation, such as `FileStream.EndRead`. `IAsyncResult` objects are also passed to methods invoked by `AsyncCallback` delegates when an asynchronous operation completes.
An object that supports the `IAsyncResult` interface stores state information for an asynchronous operation and provides a synchronization object to allow threads to be signaled when the operation completes.

---

```
class Ffmpeg
{
    NamedPipeServerStream p;
    String pipename = "mytestpipe";
    byte[] b;
    //int i, j;
    System.Diagnostics.Process process;
    IAsyncResult ar;

    public Ffmpeg()
    {

    }

    public void Start(string FileName, int BitmapRate )
    {
        p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
        b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p 
        process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86\ffmpeg.exe";
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + FileName;
        process.Start();

        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        ar = p.BeginWaitForConnection(EndWait, null);
    }

//callback when client connects
void EndWait(IAsyncResult iar){
    var state = iar.AsyncState; // fetch state -> cast to desired type
    //do something when client connected
}
```

Comment: bash.d the p.BeginWaitForConnection need something to get. Whne you make p.BeginWaitForConnection( it's asking for AsyncCallback callback, object state) what should i do ?

Comment: Bash ok i'm updating my question with exception i'm getting now.

Comment: oops updated you'r answer by mistake. But this is the exception i get.

Comment: Ok updating my question this time i changed something but still not working.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you have connected first after calling `BeginWaitForConnection`. Wait for `EndWait` to occur, first.